# Splitting several integers in java

Tags: java, split

I am very new to java. I am trying to prompt the user to enter 4 integer numbers followed by a space and eventually print them out at the end. I am a little confused with the order of how I write things out and using the split(" ");

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 4 integer numbers here: ");

        int numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
        // Need split(" "); here?







    } // End main string args here
} // End class calculations here
```

Any help or advice is appreciated. I have looked at other ways on stackoverflow but somehow I keep getting errors.

Comment: Keyboard != keyboard

Comment: There is no need to split something. Just call `keyboard.nextInt()` four times and store the returned value on 4 different variables or something like this.

Comment: What @Tom said.  However, it depends on how you want to handle the "error" case where the user enters, say, a line with only 3 integers.  Using `nextInt()` four times will then wait until the user enters a line with a fourth integer.  That is often acceptable.  But if that isn't what you want, and instead you want to display an error message and reject the input line, then you'll need to use one of the `nextLine()` and `split()` answers.

Comment: @Tom `hasNextInt()` won't necessarily return `false` if there is no more data on the line.  It waits for another line.  (Unless there is a non-integer token on the line.)

Comment: @ajb Well, yes, you're right it would request more. This is one disadvantage in using `Scanner` and `System.in` (at least for this situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 4 integer numbers here: ");

        // Scan an entire line (containg 4 integers separated by spaces):
        String lineWithNumbers = Keyboard.nextLine();
        // Split the String by the spaces so that you get an array of size 4 with
        // the numbers (in a String).
        String[] numbers = lineWithNumbers.split(" ");

        // For each String in the array, print them to the screen.
        for(String numberString : numbers) {
            System.out.println(numberString);
        }

    } // End main string args here
} // End class calculations here
```

This code will print all numbers, in case you actually want to do something with the Integers (for example mathematical operations) you can parse the String to an int, like so:

```
int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read it in one String with keyboard.nextLine
2. Use the split method of String for get an array of Strings
3. Convert every element of the array to int with Integer.parseInt
4. Print your ints.

Answer (score 1):

If would suggest to use the abilities of the `Scanner` class to retrieve numbers from the user input:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[4];
System.out.println("Enter 4 integer numbers here: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 4 && keyboard.hasNextInt(); i++) {
  numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

This code creates an array of size **4** and then loops over the user input reading the numbers from it. It will stop parsing the input if he has the four numbers, or if the user enters something different than a number. For example, if he enters `1 blub 3 4`, then the array will be `[1, 0, 0, 0]`.

This code has some advantages compared to the `nextLine` approaches of the over answers:

- you don't have to care about the integer conversion (exception handling)
- you can either write these number onto one line or each number on its own line

If you like to read an arbitrary amount of numbers, then use a `List` instead:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Enter some integer numbers here (enter something else than a number to stop): ");
while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
  numbers.add(keyboard.nextInt());
}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Comment: My mother used to say "why keep a dog and bark yourself".  This is the best answer.